# query on mongodb with nested $and within $in

Tags: mongodb

I want this query on MongoDB but I don't know how to do it:

```
OrderModel.findOneAndUpdate(
{
  status: { '$and': ['$in': [A, B] ,
                      '$and' : ['$in': [C], orderDelivery.expectedArrivalFrom :<to be smaller then a specific date>] ] },  )
```

> I mean this condition: ( status == A ) or (
>   status == B ) or (status == B
>   and orderDelivery.expectedArrivalFrom < 'some date')

Where orderDelivery is a field of OrderModel and expectedArrivalFrom is a field of orderDelivery with type Date.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your explanation your condition should be like

```
OrderModel.findOneAndUpdate(
 {
  $or: [
    {status: {$in: ['A', 'B']}},
    {
      $and: [
        {status: 'C'},
        {"orderDelivery.expectedArrivalFrom": {$lt: date}}
      ]
    }
  ]
 },
 {//update info}
);
```

Comment: the 'B' in $and should be 'C'

Comment: yes that can be as you need I followed your explanation @KamranHosseini

Comment: I haven't tested it yet in my code, But it seems to be true.